# Symmetrical pi-based html canvas translating

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, pi

In the [W3 Schools HTML Canvas Clock drawing tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_clock_numbers.asp), the clock numbers are translated around the canvas using a static multiplier (`.85`, shown below).

```
ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
```

If you didn't want to use the hardcoded/static `.85` value to position the numeral, how would you find the correct position using Sin, or Cos, or other means?

Comment: for me it's symmetrical if I change width and height of canvas

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial but it is written for and in the C programming language. Nevertheless I think you could figure out how it is done mathematically.

Comment: http://sketchytech.blogspot.de/2014/11/swift-how-to-draw-clock-face-using.html

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the answer:

```
function drawNumerals() {
var numerals = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ],
   angle = 0,
   numeralWidth = 0;

numerals.forEach(function(numeral) {
  angle = Math.PI/6 * (numeral-3);
  numeralWidth = context.measureText(numeral).width;
  context.fillText(numeral, 
     canvas.width/2  + Math.cos(angle)*(HAND_RADIUS) - numeralWidth/2,
     canvas.height/2 + Math.sin(angle)*(HAND_RADIUS) + FONT_HEIGHT/3);
});
}
```

You just have to edit it to your needs.
I found it on Github Gist [Draw circle with clock numbers](https://gist.github.com/adwpower/8708301)

Comment: Hey @habamedia; I think this more or less gets at what I'm trying to do. Are you able to provide an example if how you would integrate the Math.cos and Math.sin with the original example (`ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);`)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to scale up correctly when i tried.
Are you removing or omitting the height attribute on the canvas element like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas"
style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
drawClock();

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code determines the height it should use for the clock from the elements actual dimensions. If you dont constrain the height and width it will look wrong.

If you see you can double the size of the clock by modifying the height and width attributes of the canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" height="800px" width="800px"
style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
drawClock();

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned that I am using shapes instead of Arabic numerals, and am looking for absolutely precise symmetry, not only that the final product looks approximate.

The answer below from @habamedia looks more like what I am trying to get at, but I will have to play around with it to verify.

Comment: Maybe a better way of framing my question would have been; if you didn't want to use the hardcoded/static `.85` value to position the numeral, how would you find the correct position using Sin, or Cos, or other means....

Comment: The 0.85 value is used to say how far from the center of the clock to place the numbers. The logic to place the numbers round the clock is done by the rotation of the context by ang (and then back again so that the text is straight). Ang is increased in increments of 1/6 pi (as 2pi is 360 degrees/full circle) which perfectly spaces the numbers around the center point.